# How do I solve LNK2005: already defined

Tags: c++, lua, linker-errors, luabind

I'm working on a project with Lua and Luabind to C++. Now, in every class I want to export to C++, I write a static method Register like this:

In Button.h:

```
static luabind::scope Register();
```

In Button.cpp:

```
luabind::scope falcon::Button::Register()
{
    return 
        luabind::class_<Button, Button*>("Button")
        .def(luabind::constructor<float, float, float, float>());
}
```

For every class I already exported to Lua, this works fine. But for Button.cpp, this doesn't seem to work.

I get the following linker error:

```
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall luabind::detail::class_base::~class_base(void)" (??1class_base@detail@luabind@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall luabind::detail::function_object::function_object(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (??0function_object@detail@luabind@@QAE@P6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall luabind::detail::function_object::~function_object(void)" (??1function_object@detail@luabind@@UAE@XZ) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall luabind::detail::invoke_context::operator bool(void)const " (??Binvoke_context@detail@luabind@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall luabind::detail::invoke_context::invoke_context(void)" (??0invoke_context@detail@luabind@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall luabind::detail::object_rep::set_instance(class luabind::detail::instance_holder *)" (?set_instance@object_rep@detail@luabind@@QAEXPAVinstance_holder@23@@Z) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void * __thiscall luabind::detail::object_rep::allocate(unsigned int)" (?allocate@object_rep@detail@luabind@@QAEPAXI@Z) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class luabind::detail::class_rep * __thiscall luabind::detail::object_rep::crep(void)" (?crep@object_rep@detail@luabind@@QAEPAVclass_rep@23@XZ) already defined in Button.obj
1>luabindd.lib(luabindd.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class luabind::detail::cast_graph const & __thiscall luabind::detail::class_rep::casts(void)const " (?casts@class_rep@detail@luabind@@QBEABVcast_graph@23@XZ) already defined in Button.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>D:\Users\THijs\Dropbox\3DAE\Platform Development\Falcon Engine\main\FalconEngine\Debug\FalconEngine.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: the problem is not with static function shown. Somehow you are pulling in duplicate definitions for the named external functions into the translation unit that contains Button. You need to post more code or review the includes in that TU manually

Comment: Do you want me to post all of the code in my Button class?

Comment: I want you to shift focus to the source of the problem :) How you can present it, I don't know, because I haven't your code...

Comment: To be a slight bit less cryptic than the earlier comment: It looks like you may be explicitly including Button.cpp in one file -- possibly because Button.cpp has templated objects or functions -- and then Button.cpp is getting compiled separately.  As a result, you're getting duplicate symbol errors for each non-templated function.

Comment: Button.cpp itself doesn't have templated objects or functions. 

luabind::class_ does have templated functions, so maybe it has something to do with that?! 

I checked my includes and there no place I include Button.cpp explicitly, so the only source of the error I can think of is luabind itself... I'll check it out :)

Comment: You'll need to get rid of the LNK4098 warning first, that's a serious problem.  Compile your code with /MD, not /MT.  If you still have LNK2005 errors then review your #includes.

Comment: It is compiled with the /MDd, /MD generates the same errors, I'll check my includes a second time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the error by defining & declaring the function in the headerfile... Perhaps anyone can explain this to me why this has to be done for this class and not for, let's say, the 10 other ones I want to register with Lua?!

It's kind of weird, because I implement the function in those other classes in the .cpp...